# How to tag, label, or create Github repositories?

Tags: github

I have my own organization that hosts various repositories.  I am interested to identify whether each repository is in "alpha", "beta, or "stable" phase.

What's the easiest way to do this?

I don't see any way to specify my own custom repo type outside the ones that are built-in.  Nor a way to add a label or tag for the repositories.

The closest might be to use a topic.  But I don't see a way to create my own custom topic.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use the branches "alpha", "beta", "stable", etc for each repo phase. You can merge one branch into another(alpha -> beta) to move from one phase to another.